# Is there any way to know whether an Android App Link will open an app or not?

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, linker, universal

Is there a programmatic way to know whether a HTTPS URL will open an Android app using [Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)?

For Universal Links, the iOS equivalent of App Links, one has the ability to use the `static let universalLinksOnly: UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey` (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/openexternalurloptionskey/1648680-universallinksonly)), when linking out to make sure that a URL will open an app or not. Is there an Android App Links equivalent for this?

Comment: You can test the app link using Android Studio's  App Links Assistant. Once the link is setup, you have an option to test it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activity.TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="testapp"
            android:host="host1"
            android:path="/path1"
            android:port="8080" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then:

```
<a href="testapp://host1:8080/path1?query1=1&query2=true">Open from App</a>
```

Among them, scheme and host are required, and other requirements depend on your actual needs.

Comment: This is an answer to a completely different (much simpler) question.